# Counter doesn't count up

Tags: counter

```
while True:
def update():
    global counter
    global points
    counter = points
counter = 0
points = counter + 1
print(points)
```

First off I am very new to this I am wonder my simple counter only `print` `1` instead of counting up.

Comment: cause your code is not correctly indented?

Comment: Please reformat your code. This is not proper Python (and could explain why it's broken if this is how you have it formatted).

Comment: How do I reformat my code

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off.  Also some of your code seems to not be of use for what you're outputting.

---

Try this:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    counter = counter + 1
    print(counter)
```

I'm not sure why you are using two variables.  The `points` variable isn't doing anything.  Also you never call the `update()` function if you were trying to do that.

Maybe go read the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)?  Because you seem a little lost.

***Happy Coding!***

Comment: I seemed to be random numbers i want it to start at 0 and count up

Comment: They're not random numbers @NathanJohnson.  The numbers just count up really fast so they appear to be random.

Answer (score 0):

When posting Python please take care to maintain the indents (the spaces before each line of your code), because they are critical to how Python programs work.

- You have placed the definition of the `update()` function inside the while loop. Defining a function is not the same as running it, so the update would not actually be carried out as part of the loop. There is pretty much no reason to put a function *definition* inside a while loop.
- It would also be better for `update()` not to be a function, since it depends on both variables being global and does not really have any useful function once parameterized.
- The reset of counter to 0 is also inside the loop. This means that the counter resets every time around the loop, which is why it keeps printing 1.

This will work, although unless you have a reason for using the variable `points` it would be better not to since you only actually need `counter`:

```
counter = 0
while True:
    points = counter + 1
    counter = points
    print(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

A python program,print a number starting from 0.

```
def update():
    counter = 0
    while(True):
        print(counter)
        counter = counter + 1

update()
```